# Arrangements of n pairs of socks on a clothesline

Tags: combinatorics

n pairs of socks are hung side by side on a clothesline. The socks in each pair are identical and the pairs are different colours. How many different colour patterns can be made if no sock is next to its corresponding mate?
The answer given for the case where n is even is $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} { n \choose k } \frac{(-1)^k (2n-k)!}{2^{n-k}} $. How would this be justified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that one cannot avoid an inclusion-exclusion procedure. This means that we have to count for each $k$-tuple of pairs the number of arrangements where the socks of this particular $k$-tuple are *forced* to stay together (and other pairs *may* stay together).

Given such a $k$-tuple we have to count the number of arrangements of the $$k+2(n-k)=2n-k$$ symbols $$p_1, p_2,\ldots p_k, s_1,s_1,s_2,s_2,\ldots, s_{n-k}, s_{n-k}$$
with no restrictions, but identifying arrangements differing by an interchange of two equal $s_i$. The number of such arrangements is
$${(2n-k)!\over 2^{n-k}}\ .$$

The  $k$-tuple $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k)$ can be chosen in ${n\choose k}$ ways, and for each choice we obtain the above number of arrangements. The [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle) in its complementary form then states that the number $a_n$ of arrangements where there occurs no adjacent pair at all is given by
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}{(2n-k)!\over 2^{n-k}}\ .$$
One finds
$$a_1=0, \quad a_2=2,\quad a_3=30, \quad a_4=864, \quad\ldots\ .$$
This is sequence [A114938](http://oeis.org/A114938) in OEIS, where you may find more material about it.

The numbers $$b_n:={1\over n!}\>a_n$$
count the number of ways to pair off $2n$ seats in a row such that no two adjacent seats form a pair. One can show  "directly" that   the $b_n$ satisfy the recursion
$$b_n=(2n-1)b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}\ ,$$
from which one obtains the recursion
$$a_n=n(2n-1)a_{n-1}+n(n-1)a_{n-2}$$
for the $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Consider the case when the socks in pair $1$ **are** adjacent, and the socks in pair $2$ **are** also adjacent, and count the arrangements.

We need to arrange in a row the symbols $P_1$ and $P_2$ representing the pairs, with $S_3$ twice, $S_4$ twice and so on representing the single socks.  This is a standard "permutations with repetitions" problem and the number of arrangements is
$$\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-2}}\ .$$

Now give a similar argument for more, or fewer, adjacent pairs, and use inclusion/exclusion.

BTW it doesn't matter whether $n$ is even or odd.